# Board Column not showing on Tasks and Bugs on Query in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

what do i need to configure to show on what board column my tasks and bug is located in Azure DevOps. Currently it only displays on Epic,Feature and User Stories only.

[image]

Comment: Hi @BizApps. This is by design and cannot be customized. Please check below answer

Answer (score 1):

It is by design that Tasks and Bugs are not shown with Epics, Features, and Stories in Boards, for Tasks is not of backlog level and it is managed within Stories as child item. For details please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/get-started/what-is-azure-boards?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process#work-item-types).

Hovever you can easily create new tasks, tests and bugs from the a story's board. Please check the document [Add a task or set of tasks on Boards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/boards/add-task-checklists?view=azure-devops#add-a-task-or-set-of-tasks). You can check the document for more information about [add child items from Backlogs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/define-features-epics?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process#add-child-items)

The operation that is supported by azure devops currently is that you can setup Bugs shown with Epics, Features, and Stories. Please check documents [Set your team's preferences for tracking bugs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/show-bugs-on-backlog?view=azure-devops#set-your-teams-preferences-for-tracking-bugs)

You can also choose to hide or show one or more backlog level(Epics, Features, Stories) for Backlog navigation. For detailed information please check document [Select backlog navigation levels for your team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/select-backlog-navigation-levels?view=azure-devops).

If you want to suggest Microsoft to support showing tasks and bugs with Stories and Epics. You can [submit a feature](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html)(click suggest a feature and choose azure devops) request here.